# Using Cypress, how do I record the results as a video and then locate the folder that it's stored in?

Tags: cypress

I'm using Cypress. No issues. All tests run fine. However, I am confused about how to record the results as a video and then how to locate the folder that contains the video.

I have tried to locate the cypress/video folder per the documentation with no luck. I even tried changing the default location to folder on my C drive but the folder was not populated with the video.

Are there other steps required to initiate the recording?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Cypress will start recording videos only if it is running from the command line or in headless mode. After running the Cypress test you should see a `video` getting created under the Cypress root folder.

Lets say you have the whole Cypress project in `C:\Demo\` and the test is called `test-spec.js` available under the `integration\examples` folder.

Now `cd` to that `Demo` folder, then run the Cypress command like this:

```
`C:\Demo\node_modules\.bin\cypress run "C:\Demo\cypress\integration\examples\test-spec.js"`
```

If you have multiple spec files to run:

```
`C:\Demo\node_modules\.bin\cypress run "C:\Demo\cypress\integration\examples\"`
```

Also, make sure that the following settings are `true` in your `cypress.config.ts`:

```
video: true,
videoCompression: 32,
videoUploadOnPasses: true,
```

Also, remember that there was an issue with [Cypress recording blank videos](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress/issues/1304).